# Como usar correctamente un servicio de Laravel?

Tags: laravel, servicio

Tengo una tabla de personas, con dos campos: `nombre` y `fecha_nacimiento`. La fecha de nacimiento está grabada en ISO 8601.
Lo que quiero es crear un servicio al que pueda llamar desde un controlador y que me convierta la fecha a formato español. He creado la estructura del servicio con `php artisan make:Provider DateConvert`. He añadido el servicio a `config/app.php`, agregando, en la clave `providers`, esto: `App\Providers\DateConvert::class,`. Creo que este fichero es lo que en la documentación llama `Service container` (corregirme si me equivoco).

Luego intento en el controlador esto:

```
public function list()
{
    $gente = Person::all();

    $gente = $gente->map(function ($persona) {
        $persona->fecha_nacimiento = DateConvert($persona->fecha_de_nacimiento);
        return $persona;
    });

    return view('list')
        ->with([
            'gente' => $gente,
        ]);
}
```

Me da el siguiente error:

> Declaration of App\Providers\DateConvert::register($fecha) should be compatible with Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider::register()

No tengo ni idea de a qué se refiere. Sé que esta conversión se podría hacer mucho más fácil en el controlador, pero quiero entender como funcionan y se usan los servicios. Cuanto más leo la documentación de Laravel, menos entiendo nada. ¿Podéis darme información detallada de como funcionaría y por qué?

El service provider:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class DateConvert extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register($fecha)
    {
        return date('d-m-Y', strtotime($fecha));
    }

    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor agrega el código del Service Provider.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón. Ya lo he añadido en la pregunta.

Comment: Si puedes esperar un par de días más, te respondo con la explicación @Laura1995

Comment: Lo que haga falta. Además, viniendo de ti, ya se que la respuesta será buena. Muchas gracias.

Comment: ya fue resuelta la duda o aun no para poder ayudaros?